# Why do my apostrophe-oembed Vimeo requests fail in hosted environment?

Tags: vimeo, apostrophe-cms, oembed

I have tried to dig into this issue a few times now, but haven't had the time fully fix it.
Here is the issue: When deployed on Google Cloud Platform, I am unable to embed new videos, edit videos, or see proper previews of the already embedded videos. I get the Red X. Running locally everything works fine. Currently I have to run the app locally to edit or add any videos to my site.

What I'm seeing: When deployed this url will return a 404 `/modules/apostrophe-oembed/query` I've left out the domain and the query params, but that same url works just fine when running locally.

It is pretty tough to debug since the code runs fine when I can tinker with it.
This is primarily with Vimeo videos if that's of any consequence.

Comment: Can you include the full error/stack trace you get when this happens?

Comment: If the URL is a 404 there might not be much more. What do the other API call URLs look like in the network panel? Any chance you have a sitewide prefix that is missing from this one? A wrong hostname on it? Any other way it's not like the others, as the song goes?

Comment: @TomBoutell Could be, where is the hostname set for apostrophe? Everything else seems to work fine though. As a note this is used as a headless cms, but here is a link to one of the pages, you can open up the network panel and see the 404's: https://cms.godfreydadich.com/work/symantec

Comment: I'm asking what the URLs for other API requests, like those Apostrophe makes while you are editing on that same page, compare to the URLs for the oembed request. And maybe this question will flush out a bigger issue, like not being able to log in and edit at all for instance...

Comment: @TomBoutell All other API requests for modules like workflow and rich text seem to work just fine. Log in works.. literally everything else works.

Comment: This is definitely not a hostname issue. The response is coming from apostrophe-oembed as simply 'error'. It is thrown as a 404, but it's not a 404. I will try a video from youtube to see if it's vimeo specific, but this seems like a deeper issue with the module.

Comment: Ok, it does seem to be Vimeo specific. Youtube works from what I can tell.

Comment: okay so that's going to be an issue with how we go about doing oembed with Vimeo. Maybe they have changed something out from under us. Maybe embedding is not allowed for that particular video.

Comment: @TomBoutell I'm back at this problem again. It is definitely an oembetter/apostrophe-oembed + vimeo issue. Place ANY vimeo link here and the error occurs.. youtube has no  issues: `https://cms.godfreydadich.com/modules/apostrophe-oembed/query?url=https%3A//vimeo.com/448578435`.

Comment: This worked right away for me. I think it's possible you've been throttled for too many oembed requests. The solution to that would probably be to skip it by generating our own embed iframe code (an oembetter before handler). There are handlers like that for non-oembed-capable sites that ship in apostrophe. You could do a PR following that pattern.

Answer (score 1):

After a whole lot of debugging I discovered that Vimeo just doesn't like site scrapers. They end up blocking the domains of apps that scrape their pages regularly. That's how `oembetter` gets the oembed endpoint urls. The fix for this is a simple config in app.js.

In the modules block place this in the list of configs:

```
'apostrophe-oembed': {
   endpoints: [
        { domain: 'vimeo.com', endpoint: 'https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json' }
      ]     
    },
```

This stops the need for oembetter to scrape the page and it goes directly to vimeo's oembed endpoint.